# Зачем нужен javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()) и что он делает?

Tags: java

Иногда зачем-то пишут `javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()`  и т.д. Зачем это нужно, и что это дает?

Также я не понимаю, что делает `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)`, в интернете гуглю, а найти никак не могу..

Comment: [The Java™ Tutorials \ Concurrency in Swing \ Initial Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) и [JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated-boolean-).

Comment: Первый вопрос: http://www.skipy.ru/technics/gui_sync.html. Второй вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139088/jframe-setdefaultlookandfeeldecoratedtrue